# Checking a Python FTP connection

Tags: python, ftplib

I have a FTP connection from which I am downloading many files and processing them in between. I'd like to be able to check that my FTP connection hasn't timed out in between. So the code looks something like:

```
conn = FTP(host='blah')
conn.connect()
for item in list_of_items:
    myfile = open('filename', 'w')
    conn.retrbinary('stuff", myfile)
    ### do some parsing ###
```

How can I check my FTP connection in case it timed out during the `### do some parsing ###` line?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Send a NOOP command. This does nothing but check that the connection is still going and if you do it periodically it can keep the connection alive.

For example:

```
   conn.voidcmd("NOOP")
```

If there is a problem with the connection then the FTP object will throw an exception. You can see from the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html) that exceptions are thrown if there is an error:

**socket.error and IOError:** These are raised by the socket connection and are most likely the ones you are interested in.

**exception ftplib.error_reply:** Exception raised when an unexpected reply is received from the server.

**exception ftplib.error_temp:** Exception raised when an error code signifying a temporary error (response codes in the range 400–499) is received.

**exception ftplib.error_perm:** Exception raised when an error code signifying a permanent error (response codes in the range 500–599) is received.

**exception ftplib.error_proto:** Exception raised when a reply is received from the server that does not fit the response specifications of the File Transfer Protocol, i.e. begin with a digit in the range 1–5.

Therefore you can use a [try-catch block](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) to detect the error and handle it accordingly.

For example this sample of code will catch an IOError, tell you about it and then retry the operation:

```
retry = True
while (retry):
    try:
        conn = FTP('blah')
        conn.connect()
        for item in list_of_items:
            myfile = open('filename', 'w')
            conn.retrbinary('stuff', myfile)   
            ### do some parsing ###

        retry = False

    except IOError as e:
        print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror)
        print "Retrying..."
        retry = True
```

Comment: `ftplib` seems not to fit the Pythonic principle that there should be one obvious way to do something--or at least you'd have to give me that on `voidcmd('NOOP')`