# When using ftplib in Python 3.7, what is the proper way to detect if an ftp connection is closed or unopened?

Tags: python, error-handling, ftplib

Based on the docs and all previous SO questions, the code here should work properly, but isn't. Couldn't find any duplicates. If there are, my bad.

Basically, after calling `ftp.quit()` on a valid ftp connection, subsequent attempts to test whether it is connected fail. Running the try / except block below prior to `ftp.quit()` works properly ("Connection is open" is always printed).

**After closing the connection using ftp.quit():**

**1.** I tried catching errors when calling `ftp.voidcmd('NOOP')`.

I get an `Attribute: NoneType...` error (which should be an indication that the ftp object reset to *None*).

**2.** But, checking `if ftp is None` also fails.

**3:** And, just for additional confirmation, I check `type(ftp)`

**Code to reproduce: *(Result follows)***

```
# Connect
import ftplib
ftp = ftplib.FTP("FtpSite")
ftp.login("user","passwd")

# show success
print(ftp.getwelcome())

connected = True

# Close connection
ftp.quit()

# Is ftp still a valid obj?
print(type(ftp))

# Is ftp None?
if ftp is None:
    print("ftp is None.")
else:
    print("ftp is still assigned, but closed")


# check if open
try:
    ftp.voidcmd("NOOP")
except ftplib.all_errors as e:
    errorInfo = str(e).split(None, 1)[0]
    print(errorInfo)
    connected = False

if connected:
    print("Connection is open.")
else:
    print("Connection already closed.")
```

Result:

```
<class 'ftplib.FTP'>  # the output of print(type(ftp))

ftp is still assigned, but closed  # the output of checking if None  

Traceback (most recent call last):  # the output of calling ftp.voidcmd()
  File "./dailyfetch.py", line 27, in <module>
    ftp.voidcmd("NOOP")
  File "C:\python37\lib\ftplib.py", line 277, in voidcmd
    self.putcmd(cmd)
  File "C:\python37\lib\ftplib.py", line 199, in putcmd
    self.putline(line)
  File "C:\python37\lib\ftplib.py", line 194, in putline
    self.sock.sendall(line.encode(self.encoding))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendall'
```

Related SO questions:
[Checking a Python FTP connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170503/checking-a-python-ftp-connection)
[How to "test" NoneType in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23086383/how-to-test-nonetype-in-python)

Docs:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html

Comment: Nothing? Did I ask a question that is unsolvable? Someone here must know an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread.

The issue is that the Exception raised is *not* an ftplib error, but instead an AttributeError from the socket that is being used.

Try changing `ftplib.all_errors` to `AtributeError`.

Full code:

```
# Connect
import ftplib
ftp = ftplib.FTP("FtpSite")
ftp.login("user","passwd")

# show success
print(ftp.getwelcome())

connected = True

# Close connection
ftp.quit()

# Is ftp still a valid obj?
print(type(ftp))

# Is ftp None?
if ftp is None:
    print("ftp is None.")
else:
    print("ftp is still assigned, but closed")


# check if open
try:
    ftp.voidcmd("NOOP")
except AttributeError as e:
    errorInfo = str(e).split(None, 1)[0]
    print(errorInfo)
    connected = False

if connected:
    print("Connection is open.")
else:
    print("Connection already closed.")
```

Output:

```
220-Matrix FTP server ready.
<class 'ftplib.FTP'>
ftp is still assigned, but closed
'NoneType'
Connection already closed.
```

**EDIT:**

The "`None`" object is the **socket**, not the ftp object, which you can see by doing `type(ftp.sock)`.  Having run `ftp.quit()`, this returns `<class 'NoneType'>`.  Before this, however, it returns `<class 'socket.socket'>`, which you could use as another test which is similar to your test for checking if `ftp` is `None`, ie:

```
# Is ftp.sock None?
if ftp.sock is None:
    print("Socket is None.")
else:
    print("Socket is still assigned, but closed")
```